# Laravel - Database relationships

Tags: laravel, model, database-relations

Let's consider a simple scenario of 'Company' and 'Employee' models.

A company has many employees. Now, when I map this relationship in Laravel, what is the correct approach from the following?

Approach 1:

`Employee belongsTo() Company` and `Company hasMany() Employee`

Approach 2:

`Company belongsToMany() Employee` and `Employee hasOne() Company`

Basically, what is the difference between `belongsTo()-hasMany()` and `belongsToMany()-hasOne()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three different approaches, in your question you're mixing them up a little. I'll go through all of them.

### Many-to-many

A many-to-many relationship would mean, in your example, that a company can have multiple employees **and** that an employee can work for multiple companies.

So when you're using the `belongsToMany()` method on a relation, that implies you have a pivot table. Laravel by default assumes that this table is named after both other tables, e.g. `company_employee` in the example. Both the `Company` model and the `Employee` model would then have `belongsToMany()` relations.

### Many-to-one

However, using `hasMany()` means that it's a one-to-many relationship. If we look at the example again, a company might have many employees but each employee would only be able to be employed by one company.

In the models, that means the `Company` would have a `hasMany()` method in its relationship declaration, while the `Employee` would have a `belongsTo()` method.

### One-to-one

Finally, `hasOne()` means that it's a one-to-one relationship. What it would mean in your example is that each company may only have one employee. Since the inverse of `hasOne()` is also `belongsTo()`, in this scenario, too, every employee could be employed by only one company.

The `Company` model would then have a `hasOne()` relationship method, with the `Employee` having a `belongsTo()` method.

---

In practice, you almost always want to construct a database that is as close to reality in its representation as possible. What relationships you use depends on what your case looks like. In the example, I would guess that you want a many-to-one approach, with a foreign key on the employees table, that references the id on the companies table. But ultimately, that's up to you. Hope that helped. :)

Comment: Awesomely explained. Thanks a lot.